@render.data_frame not working for Python Shiny Express
I’ve been trying to display a DataGrid for information read from a CSV file using Shiny Express in Python. However, @render.data_frame is not working as expected, and I can’t find any info online. I was following a YouTube tutorial where it worked for them, but it’s not working for me.
Below is the code
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import calendar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from shiny import reactive
from shiny.express import render, input, ui

@reactive.calc
def dat():
    # Create a DataFrame directly
    data = {
        "order_date": [
            "2024-08-01 08:30:00",
            "2024-08-02 09:45:00",
            "2024-08-03 14:15:00",
            "2024-08-04 11:00:00",
            "2024-08-05 16:20:00"
        ],
        "sales": [250, 450, 300, 400, 550],
        "category": ["Electronics", "Furniture", "Electronics", "Furniture", "Electronics"]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    
    df["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["order_date"])
    df["hour"] = df["order_date"].dt.hour
    df["month"] = df["order_date"].dt.month_name()

    return df

with ui.card():
    ui.card_header("Sample Sales Data")
    print("I AM HERE")
    
    @render.data_frame
    def sample_sales():
        print("I AM HERE2")
        df = dat()
        print(df)
        
        return render.DataGrid(df.head(5), filter=True)

I added two print statements to debug, but it seems the function def sample_sales() does not run, so the second print statement is not executed. I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.
Has anyone faced a similar issue, or could you point out what I might be missing?

The only real problem which I see here is that you use filter = True in render.DataGrid , the argument is written filters. Is it working if you change this?

I tried using filters=True, and also removed it to see if that would help, but it's still not working.

But then we need a minimal, reproducible example here. Can you provide one where we don't have to read the .csv, we are not having access to your file. Provide code containing a small (fake) data set which is passed to data which we can directly copy and execute.

Your updated code works for me without a problem (shiny 1.0.0).
